# Access a form in asp.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, html, xhtml

All the examples I can find are in Visual Basic, but I am using C#.
I want to get the data that is in a textbox in a form.
My code so far:

```
<form action="login.aspx" method="get">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So what could I do? Because I keep getting told to do this:

```
Dim UserName
UserName = Request.Form("UserName")
```

But it doesn't work in C#.

Comment: By the way, I KNOW it's Visual Basic. That is why I posted it. I keep getting told by different sites to use that, but my site is in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code you posted is vb.net.  C# has it's own syntax and keywords.

to get the value you can use the following (not an optimal solution for webforms)

```
string userName = Request.Form["UserName"];
```

I would suggest going through some c# tutorials to get a handle on the language.  Here's the first one i found http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to do that on asp.net; simply change your markup like so:

```
<form action="login.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" runat="server" id="txtUsername" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" runat="server" id="txtPassword"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And on code behind:

```
string UserName= txtUsername.Value;
```

And yes, Shawn also caught a good one, you should use POST.

Comment: Probably needs a `runat="server"` in there, as well.

Comment: @DavidLively correct! thanks for the correction. Updated my markup.

Answer (score 2):

Your method should be POST.

```
<form action="login.aspx" method="post">
```